# I am the coat of the fourth horse. Who am I?

Tags: riddle

```
I am the fields rippling in the summer breeze,
the depths of the forest and the ocean alike.

I am the gleaming jewel of Erin, 
and the mark of some who fight over her today.

I am the lesser of two brothers,
mistaken for my twin in the light of the rising sun.

I am the signal beckoning onward,
drawing men into motion.

I am the field of luck and folly,
on which card and cube do play.

I am the eyes that burn with desire
for that which is not mine.

I am the coat of the fourth horse.
```

**Who am I?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answer:

> Green

I am the fields rippling in the summer breeze,
the depths of the forest and the ocean alike.

> All green in color.

I am the gleaming jewel of Erin, 
and the mark of some who fight over her today.

> Ireland's green countryside.  The green color of the Irish flag represents the native people of Ireland.

I am the lesser of two brothers,
mistaken for my twin in the light of the rising sun.

> Not a clue.

I am the signal beckoning onward,
drawing men into motion.

> Green traffic light.

I am the field of luck and folly,
on which card and cube do play.

> Green baize gaming table

I am the eyes that burn with desire
for that which is not mine.

> Jealousy = green.

I am the coat of the fourth horse.

> The four horsemen of the Apocalypse are depicted with the death horse being green, in at least the Vasnetsov painting.

Comment: Maybe the third clue is a reference to green and blue sharing a word in Japanese?

Comment: That's good - the "rising sun" hints that you are right.  But I know no Japanese.

Comment: f'' is correct - that is the meaning of third clue.  While Japanese does have a word for green, 'midori', things like newly-sprouted plants and traffic lights are referred to as 'ao', which seems to be somewhere between blue and cyan.